# Prove solution of differential equation is in the subspace

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $(X, \|\cdot \|)$ be a Banach space and $E$ a finite dimensional subspace of $X.$ Let $A$ be an invariant operator on $E,$ i.e. $Av \in E \,\,\,\forall v \in E.$ Let $u$ be a solution of the initial value problem: $$ \begin{cases}
      u'(t) + Au(t) = 0, & t\in \mathbb{R}\\
      u(t_0) = u_0 ∈ E, & t_0 \in \mathbb{R}
    \end{cases}$$
I need to show that $u(t) \in E \, \,\,\forall t\in \mathbb{R}.$

If we assume that $u(t) \not\in E,$ then $Au(t) \not\in E.$ I am then wondering if $u'(t)$ can be in $E$ or not.

Can somebody provide any hint or a solution proposal ?
Thanks.

Comment: Do we have uniqueness of solution to your IVP?

Comment: Can you say a solution to this DE is $$u(t)=e^{-At}u_0$$ where $$e^{-At}=I-tA+\frac{t^2}{2!}A^2-\frac{t^3}{3!}A^3-+\dots$$